# php artisan make:middleware OldMiddleware returns 'there are no commands defined in the 'make' namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I'm trying to create middleware in Laravel 4.2  when I run

```
php artisan make:middleware OldMiddleware
```

it returns 'there are no commands defined in the 'make' namespace'

however migrate command works

when I run

`php artisan list`

it shows me the list of command but there is no 'make' command indeed

?

I got this command : `php artisan make:middleware OldMiddleware` from official laravel website -

Comment: Which version of Laravel?

Comment: Laravel 4.2    ///////

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**make:middleware** artisan command was added in **Laravel 5.0**. It seems that you're running some older version of Laravel. If you want to use this command, upgrade to **Laravel 5.0**.